# Save Username/Password on Google Chrome for a localhost Address

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Google Chrome does not allow me to save a Password and Username for one of my locahost addresses.  It didn't have this problem in past versions but now I get the warning that the address is missing a .com at the end.

Does anyone know a way to force Chrome to accept credentials for one of my localhost applications?

For my server type I'd rather not use 127.0.0.1

[image: Sample of error message]

Answer (score 5):

Try adding a `.` sign at the end. The error should disappear and password suggestion on the page should work.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new text file, e.g. `my-new-passwords.csv` and insert the following content:

```
name,url,username,password,note
```

You can then add extra lines with your actual data. I didn't dig too deep into this, but here's what I got so far:

- `name` can be any identifier you want to use as far as I can tell. Just use the domain name to be sure.
- `name` is the start of the URL that has to match.
- `username` and `password` are your actual logins in plain text.
- `note` would be an arbitrary note you can add (just like in the password manager).

```
name,url,username,password,note
someserver,http://someserver/,myloginname,mypassword,
```

Once this is done, you should be able to import the file in the Password Manager and it will confirm the number of passwords it read. There's also an option to immediately delete the file just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` seems to work

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with an internal web server that needed to be accessed as http:\\SITE:456

I got around Chrome's over-helpful domain extension validation by importing the url, username, and password from a CSV.

You can run a password export from Chrome to get the CSV's format.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it work on my computer
http://127.0.0.1:3000